# How to emit/receive a signal when QWidget is enabled?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a window with 2 panels (widgets), one can be enabled when clicking on a button from the other one.

I would like to be able to set the focus to a specific object in the enabled panel when it is enabled.

I tried:

```
getNameField()->setFocus();
```

right after

```
setEnabled(true);
```

but it did nothing.

Is there a signal for this in `QWidget` documentation?  Or is there a `setTimeout` method, like in Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

In order to catch `QWidget` enabled, one must reimplement its protected function `changeEvent(QEvent *event)`

Sample code for testing enabled state:

```
if(event->type() == QEvent::enabledChange)
    ;
    /*do whatever to determine if things were enabled or disabled here */
    /* check exact case on documentation */
```

**Source:** [QWidget: enabled property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#enabled-prop)

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1:

An event filter can be used to pick up on [QEvent::EnabledChange](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qevent.html#Type-enum), and here's how:

**Event filter:**

```
#ifndef MYEVENTFILTER_H
#define MYEVENTFILTER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QEvent>
#include <QLineEdit>

class myEventFilter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    myEventFilter (QObject *parent = nullptr) {}

protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject * obj, QEvent * event) override
    {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::EnabledChange)
        {
            QWidget *w = static_cast<QWidget*>(obj);

            QLineEdit *l = w->findChild<QLineEdit*>("lineEdit");

            l->setFocus();
        }

        return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
    }
};

#endif // MYEVENTFILTER_H
```

**Implementation:**

I used a button to enable/disable a widget, and a `QLineEdit` to set its focus, as a way to demonstrate, it can be changed depending on the use case.

```
QWidget *widget = new QWidget();
QWidget *widget1 = new QWidget(widget);

QPushButton *b = new QPushButton("Add",widget);
QLineEdit *l = new QLineEdit(widget1);

widget->setMinimumSize(800,600);

widget1->setStyleSheet("background: darkblue;");
widget1->setGeometry(100,100,100,100);
widget1->setEnabled(false);

//make the button enable and disable the widget
b->connect(b, &QPushButton::clicked, [widget1](){
    if(widget1->isEnabled())
        widget1->setEnabled(false);
    else
        widget1->setEnabled(true);
});
widget->show();

l->setObjectName("lineEdit");
myEventFilter *filter = new myEventFilter();

//event filter gets installed on the object that's going to be enabled and disabled
widget1->installEventFilter(filter);
```

---

### Solution 2:

Wrap enabling/disabling the widget with a `QAction`, to use its triggered signal, as a signal for enabling/disabling.

**Implementation:**

```
QWidget *widget = new QWidget();
QWidget *widget1 = new QWidget(widget);

QPushButton *b = new QPushButton("Add",widget);
QLineEdit *l = new QLineEdit(widget1);

widget->setMinimumSize(800,600);

widget1->setStyleSheet("background: darkblue;");
widget1->setGeometry(100,100,100,100);
widget1->setEnabled(false);

QAction *add = new QAction("Add");

//QAction being triggered will enable and disable the widget
b->connect(add, &QAction::triggered, [widget1](){
    if(widget1->isEnabled())
        widget1->setEnabled(false);
    else
        widget1->setEnabled(true);
});

//connect the button to QAction
b->connect(b, &QPushButton::clicked, add, &QAction::trigger);
//Allow QAction to focus the object
b->connect(add, &QAction::triggered,[l](){ l->setFocus();});

widget->show();
```

If you have more than one object to focus, you can add a `QAction` to each one, and connect them to the enabling/disabling `QAction`, and trigger the correct one to focus the targeted object.

Here's an example:

```
QWidget *widget = new QWidget();
QWidget *widget1 = new QWidget(widget);

QPushButton *b = new QPushButton("Add",widget);
QLineEdit *l = new QLineEdit(widget1);
QLineEdit *l1 = new QLineEdit(widget1);

QVariant *v = new QVariant();
v->setValue(1);

l1->move(widget1->x(),l->y()+l->height());

widget->setMinimumSize(800,600);

widget1->setStyleSheet("background: darkblue;");
widget1->setGeometry(100,100,100,100);
widget1->setEnabled(false);

QAction *add = new QAction("Add");
QAction *enbld = new QAction("Add");
QAction *al = new QAction();
QAction *al1 = new QAction();

b->connect(add, &QAction::triggered, [widget1, enbld](){
    if(widget1->isEnabled())
        widget1->setEnabled(false);
    else
    {
        widget1->setEnabled(true);
        enbld->trigger();
    }
});


b->connect(b, &QPushButton::clicked, add, &QAction::trigger);
//first line edit action
b->connect(al, &QAction::triggered,[l](){
    l->setFocus();
});
//second line edit action
b->connect(al1, &QAction::triggered,[l1](){
    l1->setFocus();
});
//I'm using a simple circular counter, and a switch case, to demonstrate how to specify which object to focus
//you can change that to more efficient suitable ways, depending on your use case
QObject::connect(enbld,&QAction::triggered,[widget1,al,al1,v](){
        switch (v->toInt())
        {
            case 1:
                v->setValue((v->toInt())%2+1);
                al->trigger();
                break;
            case 2:
                v->setValue((v->toInt())%2+1);
                al1->trigger();
                break;
        }
});

widget->show();
```

**Note:** This is not a direct solution, nor the best one. It's just a demonstration of an idea.